# Show hide fragment using spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm trying to use the hide and show in `fragment` using `Spinner` but I don't have any idea how to do this. But when I use `buttons` I don't have a any problem in it

Any Idea how to make this?

Here's my code :

```
public void Spinners() {

        Connection connect = ConnectorClass.CONN();
        try {


            if (connect == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String query = "select window_number from window_info";
                PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("window_number");
                    data.add(id);
                }
                ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                spinner1.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
            }
        } catch
                (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                windows = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out);
                if(windows == "Window One"){

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the fragment should be shown when the spinner is clicked

Comment: What window number is coming?

Comment: `if(windows == "Window One"){ } ` in this line I want to do something that if this is the item selected the `Window One` form will be visible. But I don't know how to do that

Comment: I have posted some answer follow that.

Comment: @NigamPatro Thank you I'm trying it right now

Comment: whether this worked?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
public void Spinners() {

        Connection connect = ConnectorClass.CONN();
        try {


            if (connect == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String query = "select window_number from window_info";
                PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("window_number");
                    data.add(id);
                }
                ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                spinner1.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
            }
        } catch
                (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                windows = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out);
                if(windows == "Window One"){
                      ft.replace(R.id.container,new WindowOneFragment());
                      ft.commit();

                //Container is the Frame layout in which you want to add the fragment and WindowOneFragment is the fragment, you want to place there.
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: `WindowOneFragment()` shows error. It says `Cannot resolve symbol 'WindowOneFragment'`

Comment: @FrostyPinky WindowOneFragment is a fragment , you need to create that,